# A signal containing no pure sinusoidal components

Tags: continuous-signals

I'm trying to decipher what exactly this statement means.  So if I have a signal which has no pure sinusoidal components, does that mean I can't decompose my signal completely into sine-waves which may be amplitude/phase/period shifted?  And so I would conclude that there is also like a saw-tooth component or a square-function component mixed up in the signal as well?

Saying that the signal contains NO pure sinusoidal component makes me feel like its decomposition should not include ANY amplitude/phase/period shifted sine-waves.. but that seems a little extreme.

Could someone clarify this for me?  Thanks.

Comment: Some pathological function that was not integrable might not have a Fourier transform.  Otherwise wouldn't the existance of an FT of any non-DC signal imply that it did contain at least 1 pure sinusoid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It contains no spikes in its frequency spectrum. (What is the Fourier transform of a sinusoid?)

Answer (score 3):

As Emre said, what they probably mean that there are no *individual* (as in, stand alone), sinusoidal components. (Spikes in the spectrum), in the example they are using. (Perhaps it is a sum of many sinusouds).

I think you would be hard pressed to come across a signal that is not composed of complex exponentials (sines and cosines) at all. (I cannot imagine such a signal). Any realistic signal imagined can be decomposed into a summation of sines and cosines.

Comment: I'm trying to recall my Signals class, about 40 year ago.  It was drilled into us that any WAVEFORM can be replicated as a sum of sinusoids, but I don't know how that applies to a complex signal of "infinite" length.